# Put macbook display screen to sleep but leave external monitor on?

Tags: mac, external-display

Im connecting my macbook to my TV via the mini display port. If I put the laptop screen to sleep (via a hot corner) the TV screen also goes dark. How can I put the laptop screen to sleep but leave the TV on?

Comment: Pretty sure the standard method is to just close the lid

Comment: Then my computer goes to sleep.

Comment: http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT3131